# Binding table with knockout.js how to clear

Tags: jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I'm trying to bind following table using knockout.js using data I get from web service. Works in general but I would like to fix 3 things:

1. When I make AJAX call and data comes back I need to clear table before `ko.applyBindings(msg);`. Right now it just keeps addind and adding.
2. I have 100 test object and it get's slower and slower after 200/300 added. I expect table might contain 300 records.. EDIT! Actually it seems that it creates another 100 rows for each row. So, first call 100 rows, second call 10000 rows..
3. In order to bind I had to specify first row. It shows up when page loaded, how do I get rid of this row?

HTML:

```
<table id="mainTable" class="paddedTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 70px;">Trip No</th>
                    <th style="width: 26px;"><img src="/images/attachment_header.png" alt="Attachments"/></th>
                    <th style="width: 70px;">PO No</th>
                    <th style="width: 70px;">BOL No</th>
                    <th style="width: 70px;">Shipper No</th>
                    <th style="width: 100px;">From</th>
                    <th style="width: 100px;">To</th>
                    <th style="width: 100px;">Scheduled Pickup</th>
                    <th style="width: 100px;">Scheduled Delivery</th>
                    <th style="width: 120px;">Status</th>
                    <th style="width: 40px;">&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: d">
                <tr class="dataRow">
                    <td data-bind="text: TripId"></td>
                    <td><img src="/images/pdf_icon24.png" alt="PDF Document"/></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>tracking stuff</td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="infoLink"><strong>Info</strong></a></td>
                </tr>    
            </tbody>
```

Script:

```
function onRefreshButtonClick() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Customer/TrackShipment.aspx/GetShipments",
            data: "{ dateFrom: '" + $("#FromDateTextBox").val() + "', dateTo: '" +  $("#ToDateTextBox").val() + "' }",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                var a = msg.d;


                ko.applyBindings(msg);

                // 
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, when using Knockout you should aim to call `ko.applyBindings()` once.  After you have initialized your View Model you will take actions that manipulate it, allowing Knockout's two-way binding to dynamically change your UI.

Here is a sample fiddle that simulates what I think you are trying to do.  It initializes the View Model, makes an AJAX call to load the first 100 rows, and then allows the user to click refresh to reload.

http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/aTuMv/

1. Clearing the table is as simple as `self.data([]);`
2. Your row explosion is because of calling `ko.applyBindings()` multiple times.
3. You can disable the table rendering with an `if` binding

Example:

```
<table id="mainTable" class="paddedTable" data-bind="if: data().length > 0">
```

This will render the table only if data has elements